# What am I doing wrong with functions?

Tags: c, gtk

I am trying to create functions instead of having bunch of code in main but I am not able to do that since I am doing something wrong with the functions, here is what my code looks like:

```
void static notebook(GtkWidget *table, GtkWidget *notebook) {
 notebook = gtk_notebook_new();
 ...
 attaching table to notebook
 ...
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
 GtkWidget *table;
 GtkWidget *notebook;

 ...
 notebook(table, notebook);
 ...
}
```

Could someone point out my problem and help me fix it please?

Comment: What is the error you get?

Comment: Why are you not able to do? What is the problem you are facing?

Comment: Well it manages to compile but when I run the program it doesn't start at all.

Comment: Problem could be somewhere else, Is it working if you use remove function call and add the code to main.

Comment: It works perfectly if I just add the code from that function to main, but when I place the same code in a function it doesn't want to start.

Comment: Somethng looks 'off' about 'notebook'.  To start with, you have a function name, parameter and argument all called 'notebook' and it's VERY CONFUSING.   The, you pass a notebook instance pointer into notebook() and aparrently then reseat the argument with new().  You are aware that the notebook* instance created in the function will not be propagated back to main()?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem seems to be that you are assuming that parameters are both for input and ouput of a function. But in C, function parameters are always copies. So when you do:

```
void static notebook(GtkWidget *table, GtkWidget *notebook) {
    notebook = gtk_notebook_new();
```

You are modifying the local copy of the `notebook` pointer, not the one from `main`. The `notebook` pointer in `main` remains uninitialized.

To do what you try, minimum changes, would be:

```
void static notebook(GtkWidget **table, GtkWidget **notebook) {
    *notebook = gtk_notebook_new();
    ...

int main() {
 GtkWidget *table;
 GtkWidget *notebook;

 ...
 notebook(&table, &notebook);
```

But doing that with every pointer is ugly and cumbersome. So I would recommend some refactoring:

1. Functions that create a thing should return that thing.
2. Functions that take a lot of related values should take a single value of type `struct whatever`.
3. Remember that struct parameters in C are usually passed as pointers, so you get the in-out parameter for free!

Something like this:

```
struct Notebook
{
    GtkWidget *table;
    GtkWidget *notebook;
};

void static notebook(struct Notebook *notebook) {
     notebook->notebook = gtk_notebook_new();
     ...
}
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
 Notebook nb;

 ...
 notebook(&nb);
 ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

take param `"GtkWidget *table"` for example, you only pass a pointer parameter to the function, and allocate memory to it : `table = new xxx`.

but `GtkWidget *table` here is a temp param only exist in function notebook, there are no way it can affect the real parameters in main.  `GtkWidget *table`, `GtkWidget *notebook`'s values stay unchanged after "notebook" function is finished.

so you can use pointer to pointer in notebook function's declaration, like this

```
 void static notebook(GtkWidget **table) {
     *table = new gtk_notebook_new();
 }
```

then in main, invoke like this:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
 GtkWidget *table;

 notebook(&table);
 ...
}
```

that should do it.